# Poco Logging with std::wstring or wchar_t

Tags: c++, poco-libraries, wchar-t

Is it possible to log `std::wstring` with the Poco Logger?

Like in this short example:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Logger& logger = Logger::get("Testlogger");
    std::wstring WStringMessage = L"Message as a WString";
    std::string StringMessage = "Message as a String";
    //logger.information(WStringMessage); //Did not compile because it only takes a String
    logger.information(StringMessage);


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a possible Solution or did i have to convert every `std::wstring` to a `std::string`?

And how is the `std::wstring` Support in other Poco Libraries like the XML one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poco interfaces are utf-8 only, so you will have to convert the string to utf-8 before sending it to the logger:

```
std::string msg;
Poco::UnicodeConverter::convert(WStringMessage, msg);
logger.information(msg);
```

For XML, see [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.8.1/XML/include/Poco/XML/XMLString.h#L29), but basically the recomendation is the same - use utf-8.